# Why can't I call a custom method on an instance of a Waterline ORM model/result?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

Unless it is defined as an attribute method?

**Model**

```
module.exports = Object.assign({}, sails.config.model, {
  attributes: {
  ...
```

**Generic model method in config/model.js**

```
module.exports.model = {
  mySaveWithPromise: function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.save({ populate: false }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Triggered with**

```
User.findOne({email: "email@example.com"})
  .then(function(user) {
    user.firstname = 'newName';
    return user.mySaveWithPromise()
  });
```

Resulting in...

`TypeError: user.mySaveWithPromise is not a function`

I can add that to `api/config/models.js` in `attributes` and it is fine, but the documentation warns against adding asynchronous methods to `attributes`. In my case, I'm guessing something like a generic output of the model could cause a save.

The weird part is that `mySaveWithPromise` does exist as a key of the object. I suspect I'll just put this method in a service and pass the instance to it, but I'm curious to understand the basic distinction in the objects.

Comment: Please show model code with your custom function.

Comment: Ok I've updated it. I've tried various methods of defining this method across all the models. The fact that it works in `attributes` and on `User`, but not on a result makes me think it's just intentional and not workable.

Comment: Side note: Use `{}` as target in `Object.assign`. E.g. `Object.assign({}, sails.config.model, { attributes ...`